# Why RSS script doesn't load? Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, rss

I have this code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
<!-- start feedwind code -->
<!-- select protocol http or https -->
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$.holdReady(true);
$.getScript("http://feed.mikle.com/js/rssmikle.js", 
function() { $.holdReady(false); });
console.log( "Load was performed." );
</script>

<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://feed.mikle.com/js/rssmikle.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript">
var params = {
  rssmikle_url: "http://althouse.blogspot.com",
  rssmikle_frame_width: "400",
  rssmikle_frame_height: "400",
  frame_height_by_article: "3",
  rssmikle_target: "_blank",
  rssmikle_font: "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",
  rssmikle_font_size: "12",rssmikle_border: "off",
  responsive: "off",rssmikle_css_url: "",
  text_align: "left",
  text_align2: "left",
  corner: "off",
  scrollbar: "on",
  autoscroll: "on",
  scrolldirection: "up",
  scrollstep: "3",
  mcspeed: "20",
  sort: "Off",
  rssmikle_title: "on",
  rssmikle_title_sentence: "",
  rssmikle_title_link: "",
  rssmikle_title_bgcolor: "#0066FF",
  rssmikle_title_color: "#FFFFFF",
  rssmikle_title_bgimage: "",
  rssmikle_item_bgcolor: "#FFFFFF",
  rssmikle_item_bgimage: "",
  rssmikle_item_title_length: "55",
  rssmikle_item_title_color: "#0066FF",
  rssmikle_item_border_bottom: "on",
  rssmikle_item_description: "on",
  item_link: "off",
  rssmikle_item_description_length: "150",
  rssmikle_item_description_color: "#666666",
  rssmikle_item_date: "gl1",
  rssmikle_timezone: "Etc/GMT",
  datetime_format: "%b %e, %Y %l:%M %p",
  item_description_style: "text+tn",
  item_thumbnail: "full",
  item_thumbnail_selection: "auto",
  article_num: "15",
  rssmikle_item_podcast: "off",
  keyword_inc: "",
  keyword_exc: ""
  };
(function(params) {
console.log( "Function started" );

    feedwind_show_widget_iframe(params);
    }
)(params);</script>
<div style="font-size:12px; text-align:center; width:300px;">
<a href="http://feed.mikle.com/" target="_blank" style="color:#CCCCCC;">RSS Feed Widget</a>
<!--Please display the above link in your web page according to Terms of Service.--></div>
<!-- end feedwind code --><!--  end  feedwind code -->
```

It should load RSS from mikle.com so you should see list of posts. I want to load the script using Jquery. I used $.holdReady(true); so the function feedwind_show_widget_iframe(params); shouldn't be called before the script is downloaded. Also I see logs in console that the file was loaded and then the function is called. If I uncomment the script tag with mikel's RSS then everything works but I want to load it dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `getScript` you pass it a callback (`function() { $.holdReady(false); }`) to execute once the script has loaded.

You've put the code which depends on that script so it runs immediately after you start requesting the script instead of inside that callback where it would run after the script became available.